# How to programmatically render dustjs template server side in nodejs

Tags: dust.js

How I can render dustjs template programmatically in nodejs at server side.

```
dust.render("test", { data: "test" }, function(err, out) {
  var datastring = out;
});
```

which doesn't seems working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the template available in Node's JavaScript execution environment. Here is an example of how to make that happen:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');

// Read the compiled Dust template.
var compiledTemplate = fs.readFileSync('path/to/compiled/dustTemplate.js');

// Execute the compiled Dust template to make it available
// in the current execution context
vm.runInThisContext(compiledTemplate);

// Render the Dust template.
dust.render('test', {data: 'test'}, function(err, out) {
  console.log(out);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, did figure out. But one question, is vm required? can we avoid nodejs vm module.

Comment: `vm` is the only way I have found to get an external file to execute in the node context.

Comment: OK, VM has security glitch. So I'm thinking to use pre-complied javascript template itself in code. Will write .sh file in start up script to compile and attach. What do you think on that approach?